# What is wrong with my CSS alignment in my CODE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the Z to come in the middle of the cricle but I am not sure why its not coming in the middle. My code outputs this

[image]

```
<li class="avatar"><span class="profile-initials">Z</span></li>
```

This is the CSS I have on my application

```
.avatar {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}


.profile-initials {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: what happens when you change the margin-right to something like 8px?

Comment: `.profile-initials { line-height: 25px; text-align: center; }`

Comment: Make sure you use https://jsfiddle.net/ next time you have an HTML question ! lol

Comment: @PatrickSimard or SO snippets, they work fine until you need JSX and other hipster stuff… :)

Comment: Indeed hehe anyway, as long as we can play with the code and share an awnser ^^ (When possible)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without looking at all of your code but the CSS could be much simpler using something like flexbox.
As for your code it seems your padding left and padding bottom are pushing it out of the frame and your and the border radius just makes it look like its outside of the circle.
Here is what I quickly came up with I hope it helps.

```css
li {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  flex-grow: 2;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 18px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="name">Veris Veritatis</span><span class="icon">Z</span></li>
</ul>
```